# Scientific notation when importing from Excel in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb

I have a C#/.Net job that imports data from Excel and then processes it. Our client drops off the files and we process them. I don't have any control over the original file.

I use the OleDb library to fill up a dataset. The file contains some numbers like 30829300, 30071500, etc... The data type for those columns is "Text".

Those numbers are converted to scientific notation when I import the data. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What data type are you importing the string of numbers into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OleDb library **will**, more often than not, mess up your data in an Excel spreadsheet.  This is largely because it forces everything into a fixed-type column layout, *guessing* at the type of each column from the values in the first 8 cells in each column.  If it guesses wrong, you end up with digit strings converted to scientific-notation.  Blech!

To avoid this you're better off skipping the OleDb and reading the sheet directly yourself.  You can do this using the COM interface of Excel (also blech!), or a third-party .NET Excel-compatible reader.  [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) is one such library that works reasonably well, and has an interface that's very similar to Excel's COM interface.

Answer (score 5):

One workaround to this issue is to change your select statement, instead of SELECT * do this:

```
"SELECT Format([F1], 'General Number')  From [Sheet1$]"
 -or-
"SELECT Format([F1], \"#####\")  From [Sheet1$]"
```

However, doing so will blow up if your cells contain more than 255 characters with the following error:
"Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."

Fortunately my customer didn't care about erroring out in this scenario.

This page has a bunch of good things to try as well:
http://www.dicks-blog.com/archives/2004/06/03/external-data-mixed-data-types/

Comment: Hey. I used this fix and it seemed to fix things for me. The problem is it seems to round every number so that the last two digits are zeroes. For example 12345678 becomes 12345600. Does anyone know how I would fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Using this connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\"
```

with Excel 2010 I have noticed the following.  If the Excel file is open when you run the OLEDB SELECT then you get the current version of the cells, not the saved file values.  Furthermore the string values returned for a long number, decimal value and date look like this:

```
5.0130370071e+012
4.08
36808
```

If the file is not open then the returned values are:

```
5013037007084
£4.08
Monday, October 09, 2000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the actual .XSLX file using Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool (or simply unzip the file and view the XML in notepad) you will see that Excel 2007 actually stores the raw data in scientific format.

For example 0.00001 is stored as 1.0000000000000001E-5

```
<x:c r="C18" s="11" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <x:v>1.0000000000000001E-5</x:v>
</x:c>
```

Looking at the cell in Excel its displayed as 0.00001 in both the cell and the formula bar. So it not always true that OleDB is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the easiest way is to choose Zip format, rather than text format for columns with large 'numbers'.

Comment: Like I said above, I have no control over the file. The client creates that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting the value of the field to (int) or perhaps (Int64) as you are reading it?

Comment: I don't "read" the file, the OleDb API does that. I simply invoke the "fill" method on the OleDbDataAdapter and pass in a DataSet.The Dataset is then filled up with juicy delicious data.

Comment: Is the dataset strongly typed so that field expects a number?

Comment: No, it is not strongly typed.

Comment: Try creating a strong typed dataset for it.  That should convert it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the IMEX=1 connection string option and TypeGuessRows registry setting on google.
In truth, there is no easy way round this because the reader infers column data types by looking at the first few rows (8 by default). If the rows contain all numbers then you're out of luck.

An unfortunate workaround which I've used in the past is to use the HDR=NO connection string option and set the TypeGuessRows registry setting value to 1, which forces it to read the first row as valid data to make its datatype determination, rather than a header.
It's a hack, but it works. The code reads the first row (containing the header) as text, and then sets the datatype accordingly.

Changing the registry is a pain (and not always possible) but I'd recommend restoring the original value afterwards.

If your import data doesn't have a header row, then an alternative option is to pre-process the file and insert a ' character before each of the numbers in the offending column. This causes the column data to be treated as text.

So all in all, there are a bunch of hacks to work around this, but nothing really foolproof.

Comment: i tried IMEX=1 property ..the con string is "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=#FILEPATH#;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1" but value comes as 2,13123219999999E+18...........

Comment: You have to set the registry entry TypeGuessRows too. Like I said, it's an unfortunate hack.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but was able to work around it without resorting to the Excel COM interface or 3rd party software. It involves a little processing overhead, but appears to be working for me.

1. First read in the data to get the column names
2. Then create a new DataSet with each of these columns, setting each of their DataTypes to string.
3. Read the data in again into this new
   dataset. Voila - the scientific
   notation is now gone and everything is read in as a string.

Here's some code that illustrates this, and as an added bonus, it's even StyleCopped!

```
public void ImportSpreadsheet(string path)
{
    string extendedProperties = "Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";
    string connectionString = string.Format(
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"{1}\"",
        path,
        extendedProperties);

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Worksheet1$]";
            connection.Open();

            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
            using (DataSet columnDataSet = new DataSet())
            using (DataSet dataSet = new DataSet())
            {
                columnDataSet.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                adapter.Fill(columnDataSet);

                if (columnDataSet.Tables.Count == 1)
                {
                    var worksheet = columnDataSet.Tables[0];

                    // Now that we have a valid worksheet read in, with column names, we can create a
                    // new DataSet with a table that has preset columns that are all of type string.
                    // This fixes a problem where the OLEDB provider is trying to guess the data types
                    // of the cells and strange data appears, such as scientific notation on some cells.
                    dataSet.Tables.Add("WorksheetData");
                    DataTable tempTable = dataSet.Tables[0];

                    foreach (DataColumn column in worksheet.Columns)
                    {
                        tempTable.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, typeof(string));
                    }

                    adapter.Fill(dataSet, "WorksheetData");

                    if (dataSet.Tables.Count == 1)
                    {
                        worksheet = dataSet.Tables[0];

                        foreach (var row in worksheet.Rows)
                        {
                            // TODO: Consume some data.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: darn! doesn't this kind of problem make you want to rip your hair out?

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution from somewhere else but it worked perfectly for me.
No need to make any code change, just format excel columns cells to 'General" instead of any other formatting like "number" or "text", then even Select * from [$Sheet1] or Select Column_name from [$Sheet1] will read it perfectly even with large numeric values more than 9 digits

Answer (score -1):

I googled around this state..
Here are my solulition steps

- For template excel file

1-format Excel coloumn as Text
2- write macro to disable error warnings for Number -> text convertion

```
  Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = Ture
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False
End Sub
```

- On codebehind

3- while reading data to import
try to parse incoming data to Int64 or Int32....