# SQL SSIS Convert question

Tags: sql, ssis

I have an excel file I'm converting to a prn in an SSIS package. My issue. One of my columns has currency, everything should have a decimal point but not all the numbers do. For example if there are no cents it simply reads 10425. What I need to happen in SSIS is to make is read 10425.00 just as the other numbers in the file already do.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Derived Column transformation to convert the data type.  I don't think think the Currency (DT_CY) data type will force the decimal places for you, but you can use the Decimal (DT_DECIMAL) data type.

```
(DT_DECIMAL,2)MyMoneyColumn
```

Comment: I tried this but it still spit out the same way. I was thinking of this 
(DT_DECIMAL,2)Round((DT_Decimal,2)[Copy of Debit Amt] / (DT_DECIMAL,2))   would that work?

Comment: @gabrielVa, what does the Derived Column transformation editor say is the output data type?  And, yes, you can try your expression; it should work.

Comment: HI Bobs, the data type is decimal[DT_DECIMAL]. The expression is (DT_DECIMAL,3)[Copy of Debit Amt].

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is relying on a registry key to determine how many rows to sample.  If you are using default settings, then it may only be checking the first 8 rows.  You can increase the number of rows it uses by modifying the TypeGuessRows key in the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel.  You can read about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141683.aspx), [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281517), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551203/help-with-a-oledb-connection-string-for-excel-files), and [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/nickwienholt/archive/2006/03/15/86379.aspx).