# read excel to datatable with intermixed data

Tags: excel, datatable, oledb

I want to read excel to datatable.But I have a problem.I have a column "ALS" which contains mixed  type data.When I read excel to dataset "Kukla" is DbNul value instead.I cant read such columns all datas

example, column data:
2000
Kukla
2000
1000
1000

```
String sConnectionString =
                    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                    "Data Source=" + "C:\\DrcrUpload\\" + filePath + ";" +
                    "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
            OleDbConnection objConn;
            objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);

 OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM" + "[" + name + "]", objConn);

objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232281/oledb-mixed-excel-datatypes-missing-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options

1.Change the registry setting [TypeGuessRows](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/initializing-the-microsoft-excel-driver-HP001032159.aspx) = 0

2.List all possible type variations in the first 8 rows as 'dummy data' (eg memo fields/nchar(max)/ errors #N/A etc)

This thread may help also [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738407/is-there-a-better-way-to-indicate-null-values-in-excel/5761022#5761022)