# Read excel columns as text

Tags: c#, excel

I want to read all columns as text values only from an excel file in a web application irrespective of the type of the data(date, number etc).

Please see the connection string used. Only ACE driver is installed and we can't use any other drivers in production server.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myOldExcelFile.xls;
                             Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";
```

Setting `IMEX=1` doesn't work. It returns null for some values.

I could see a lot of articles but am couldn't see a right answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So your connection works? The issue you're having is reading the data? If so, can you post a little but of the code where you are extracting the data out of the excel file

Comment: @astroboy: Yes connection string works and data is loaded into data table. But with null for some value. there is one column which has numeric values. if i put a text value in any of the cell in that column then it is treated as null.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are after [ACE work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551203/help-with-a-oledb-connection-string-for-excel-files/4663674#4663674)

Unfortunately, you can't set ImportMixedTypes or TypeGuessRows from the connection string since those settings are defined in the registry. For the **ACE** OleDb driver, they're stored at

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity
>   Engine\Engines\Excel

in the registry. So, you can simplify your connection string to get rid of some of those extended properties.

Once you set `TypeGuessRows` to 0 and `ImportMixedTypes` to Text in the registry, you should get the behavior you are expecting.

---

Or you can use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to read the file. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelTut
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:/C.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

code taken from [read excel file via interop](http://dontbreakthebuild.com/2011/01/30/excel-and-c-interop-with-net-4-how-to-read-data-from-excel/)

Comment: Is there any other workaround? We cant change the Registry values since there are multiple application hosted in the production server.