# Excel VBA/SQL Error on Sharepoint "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only."

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, sharepoint

I am using **ACE.OLEDB** inside Excel to run SQL and use my sheets as though they are a database.
On my PC local drive everything works.

Once I upload the file to SharePoint and launch it I get:

> error number : -2147467259
> error description : "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only."

On the net I found some people solving such a problem by changing their connection string and adding like IMEX=1 to the extended properties. I tried some suggestions, but it didn't work.

I only do a Select (not an Insert)with my SQL , so why does it need more than read-only permissions?

I can manually create a file or folder in SharepPoint, that's why I don't think it's a SharePoint problem.

I prepare my SQL request and call the OpenRecordset which calls the GetConnection function.

```
sql = "SELECT Distinct Offres FROM ['" & sMySheet & "$'] WHERE Domaine IS NOT NULL AND Domaine = '" & sTempDomaine & "';"
Set rst = OpenRecordset(sql)
```

The above line will call the OpenRecordset function with the sql request

```
Public Function OpenRecordset(sql As String) As Object       
    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adCmdText = &H1
    
    Set OpenRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    OpenRecordset.Open sql, GetConnection(), adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
End Function
```

Then OpenRecordset will call the GetConnection and here is where I get the error

```
Private Function GetConnection() As Object
    Dim m_Connection As Object 
    
    If m_Connection Is Nothing Then
        Set m_Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        'Error at the following line
        m_Connection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
    End If
    Set GetConnection = m_Connection
 End Function
```

I get the error at this line:

```
 m_Connection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
```

[image]

Comment: No, at all, and tried it from different users/pc and getting the same error

Comment: If `ThisWorkbook.FullName` is an HTTP path then I don't think you can make the connection

Comment: I am running only an SQL Select, the code of my sql request is above, as for the file name, if am launching it from the sharepoint logicially the fullname will be like : https://mysharepoint/myexcelfile.xlsm (is there anyway to have something else ? )
what should I try ?

Comment: See https://www.google.com/search?q=ADO+query+Excel+on+sharepoint+site:stackoverflow.com for similar previous posts here.  There are suggestions involving making a UNC path from the HTTP URL, but I've never had any success with those (basically any suggestions involving `DavWWWRoot` do not seem to work).  If the folder is synced on your local PC there are methods to get the local path, but it's all a lot more complex than accessing an Excel on the local filesystem or from a network folder.

Comment: I can sync using office 365, but I am not sure if what you are saying is the problem, because I saw already before posting too many users solving their problem by changing the connection string, why in my case it won't work on sharepoint while the others succeded ?

Comment: Can you point to a specific example post where that worked?  Accessing a file via HTTP is completely different from accessing a file on a local disk.

Comment: here is an expl, but he is talking about a drive, but even if I use sync to link my sharepoints file to OneDrive, the thisworkbook.filename is giving back an http link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55794161/how-to-fix-error-cannot-update-database-or-object-is-read-only-excel-databas

Comment: here are some questions if you or someone else can answer plz So for you, it's impossible to use an excel file on sharepoint if it uses SQL ? Did I got it well ?  You said that the problem in my code comes from "ThisWorkbook.FullName", which returns an https link right ? is there any way to change "ThisWorkbook.FullName" by something else ?

Comment: Last question, as you see I use only a select no updates, so why it needs more persmessions ? I am not using any Insert or Update, my sql select is above, where is the problem it's only a read only instruction,so why do I get the error ?

Comment: The error message you're getting is a red herring I think - it's not about update/no update but about HTTP vs. regular drive access. The driver you're using just doesn't work *at all* over HTTP. If you want a work-around, save a copy of the file to your local `Temp` folder: you can then use the SQL query approach with no problem.

Comment: thanks for your comment. The problem is that I want it on sharepoint to make the work shared between 4 persons, If I will save it locally, I will loose this advantage.
Do you think that I can modify something in my connection to tell that I want a read only database so maybe in this case I won't get the error ? maybe my connection is asking for write permissions so am getting the error even if am not using insert or update ? what do you think ?

Comment: It's completely unelated to read vs. write.   That driver *does not work at all* over HTTP, and I'm not aware of one that does.

Comment: Okay, so it's not related to my code itself, it's just a question of drivers that are not made to work on sharepoint links, I have to try to map a local drive and try on it right ?

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks, I solved my problem and posted the answer, thanks you are the only one who tried to help and your comment was very usefull to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, so I am posting the answer because it may help anyone else, especially that no one provided me an answer.
Based on the comments of Tim Williams, I understood that the problem is not my code itself, but the ThisWorkbook.Fullname that returns the https link of the sharepoint and not a local drive.
Thus, I searched and ended by finding a solution to convert the Http, to local drive, based on the solution here :
I choosed the **Solution 2 - Standalone Function (works on Windows and macOS)**
[Excel's fullname property with OneDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive/73577057#73577057)

On the same time, I had to map a drive of my sharepoint using the microsoft suggested method :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-a-network-drive-to-a-sharepoint-library-751148de-f579-42f9-bc8c-fcd80ccf0f53

Combining both, I solved my problem.

Thanks to anyone who read this question even if couldn't provide me help and thanks to Tim Williams.

Comment: Good to see you found a solution!

Comment: thanks again, you were the only one who helped and pointed me to the right direction, before your comment I was focused on finding a real bug in my code/logic / permissions