# C# database error while running application on Clients Computer

Tags: c#, .net, localdb

I have created a project and so far in that project I am using `localdb` to create a database, reading a CSV file from a shared drive.

I have copied a .exe file from `bin\Debug` and copied that onto the client's computer.  I am getting the following error, can someone please help:
[[image: Error: Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.]

Is it because my client does not have sqlserver or localdb installed?
I need to create an application without requiring any setup to be installed at client machine.

Please let me know if it is possible. Thanks

Comment: put whole Exception Text here instead of image

Comment: Check that user has write permissions on the directory the database is in.  The line just above the Continue button says "Cannot Update: Database or object is read-only" would indicate something like that to me.

Comment: Is the error happening while reading the excel file? Can you check here -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341535/what-is-the-default-value-of-imex-in-oledb/28569981#28569981

Comment: LocalDb has to be installed on your clients computer. Otherwise it's not usable by your application.

Comment: LocalDb is more or less a customized SqlExpress ... and just like SqlExpress it needs to be installed by running the Setup.