# How do I set up a connection to query data inside an Excel .xls file using Excel 2002?

Tags: excel, vba, database, odbc

I am writing a small application in Excel 2002 and I need to store numbers in some format, it can be a string.
The tables I have a 1:1 relationship and other table is just a table of one column so using access is not necesary and having to have another file is something I'd like to avoid.
So, I want to store it in separate sheets.

However, I like the benefits of SQL for querying and I need it.
I tried using some ADODB connection strings to reach this but I cannot achieve it.

I used the following code:

```
 Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, output As String, sql As String
    
    '---Connecting to the Data Source---
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"
        .Open
    End With
```

Also, do I have to use ODBC or should I use OLE DB? I don't know if OLE DB could be used to query in excel files.

Also, is it possible to do inserts with SQL using this ODBC or OlE DB?
I tried different providers in the connection string, and I checked the ADO references to be available.

Also, I get this error:
"Error 3706. The specified provider could not be found. It may not be installed properly."

Comment: What error do you get exactly? Is it when you try to open the connection or later on when you try to run a SQL query?

Comment: I'll edit my question, but answering you directly, it says something like,
"Error 3706. The specified provider could not be found. It may not be installed properly." I translated it so i don't know if works are 100% the same.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. It might be a problem related to what library you have on you system. What version of Windows do you use and is it 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @DecimalTurn Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Connection issue

First, there was an error in your Provider string, it should not contain the part with `Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;` since this is part of the connection string. So it should look like this:

```
    .Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"
```

### ODBC vs OLEDB

I've never used ODBC, but based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1120005/5958842), you can't use it to query an Excel file, so OLEDB is the way to go.

---

### Insert Statement

Once you have a working ADODB connection, insert query should work as hoped. I'm providing an example below that worked for me, but there is a few caveats:

- I'm using the ACE.OLEDB.12.0 instead of JET.OLEDB.4.0 with Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2112 Build 16.0.14706.20000) 64-bit on Windows 10.
- I'd suggest to set Mode=ReadWrite in your connection string to avoid potential writting permission issues (but it might work even without it.).
- Regarding the IMEX setting, I was having errors when it was set to IMEX=1, so I switched to IMEX=0 (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341535/what-is-the-default-value-of-imex-in-oledb).

#### The example

With a workbook named **Data.xls** with the first sheet named **Data** and the following data :

[image]

<sup>[Data for copy-paste](https://itty.bitty.site/#/data:text/html;charset=utf-8;bxze64,XQAAAAT//////////wAeHQgmOm3if1cj0EddAG11avRu8JLrozXRddsoRVlEd631IerpCKQfigEc8IKM3RZ0EQDwVblTCEp0g7dKYmwzrKnFFa6tLekZ7iq1H1WxEzJksDOJjaJFh1gsUXtiQw/xyy2dC/NX2lyH8i2npFJDSn3Wu28C5tWAQzdzFMq+Q4vSROt3BD8JdDRou0ilNgGCOnHI0Ca9Hz/nIj6If1WCmdcN6z1S/sPnpUivkjz/MUea3qnDIpuZHw4mvhLoqyPj4EnjqDR5pgOLLLTgZtNEcbE//845JgA=)</sup>

I can run the following:

```vb
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Data.xls")
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data")

'Create connection
Dim conn As Object
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & wb.FullName & ";" & "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0;Mode=ReadWrite;"
    .Open
End With

'Compose the INSERT statement.
Dim query As String
Const sep = ", "
query = "INSERT INTO [" & ws.Name & "$] " & _
    "(Id, Name, Age) " & _
    " VALUES (" & _
    4 & sep & _
    "'" & "Joe" & "'" & sep & _
    40 & _
    ")"

'Execute the statement.
conn.Execute query, adCmdText

'Close the connection
conn.Close
```

And it should insert the data as follow:

[image]

---

### Should you use ACE or JET?

If JET works for you, you might as well use it. Based on [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/how-to-get-a-x64-version-of-jet/ba-p/315933) , you should also have the 32-bit version of ACE available with Windows 7 to work with Excel 2002 (32-bit), but based on your comment it seems like it's causing some problems.

[See also some interesting answer about JET vs ACE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14401857/5958842).

Comment: Weird enough, I could do a select and an insert statement having 64bit OS windows 10 and excel 2002, using Jet OLE DB 4.0.
However I'll try with the one you wrote, ACE OLE DB 12.0 
However, I ignore the difference between the two.

Comment: By the way, I'm not having success doing a delete from statement.
I definitely can't use ACE OlEDB but can use Jet.
When I try with ACE, the excel file closes abruptly like it crashes.

Comment: @MisterEquis In your comment, you say that you could do a select and an insert with JET, but in you question you said that you couldn't. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I initially couldn't but I can now. I think I had the connection string wrong.
However it's weird that I can with jet and not with ace, since you said I wouldn't be able to use Jet in a 64bit OS.
Maybe it's that the 2002 version of office comes with it, but not 2010+ versions.

Comment: @MisterEquis I now realize that I misread the original articles. It's not that the 32-bit version of JET doesn't run on a 64-bit Windows, it's just that it doesn't run natively. But since you have 32-bit Excel, it should work. I've rewritten my answer to account for this.