# Select query not reading alphanumeric values in VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am reading excel data using Select query in VBA but query is not reading the line items where Column "TEILENUMMER" is alphanumeric like 61615A27D68 but able to read the line items where "TEILENUMMER" is numeric like 61627356223.

```
Dim objConn As Object

Dim objRecordSet As Object

Dim objRecCmd As Object


Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Set objRecCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

Set objRecCmd_Update = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

strFolderPath = "/testexcel"


strquery = "Select [BUNO],[RECHNR],[RECHDAT] from [Tabelle1$] where ([RECHNR] ='" & StrInvoiceNumber & "' AND ([TEILENUMMER] Is Not Null) AND ([TEILENUMMER] <> 0))")


objConn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFolderPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;IMEX=1""")

'Set objConn.Open = objConn.Execute(Source, Options:=Options)

Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")



objRecordSet.CursorLocation = adUseClient


objRecCmd.ActiveConnection = objConn


objRecCmd.CommandText = strQuery



objRecordSet.Open objRecCmd, , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic


                 If Not objRecordSet.BOF And Not objRecordSet.EOF Then

                    objRecordSet.MoveFirst

                 End IF
```

Comment: Does it work if you add double quotes around zero `[TEILENUMMER] <> "0"`

Comment: So I just want all the values except where TEILENUMMER is NULL or 0. that means I want values where TEILENUMME is numeric or alphanumeric. Above query is working perfectly only issue its not taking alphanumeric values

Comment: Does it work if you compare with `"0"` instead of `0`?

Comment: Yes , that will not work

Comment: What about `[TEILENUMMER] <> '0'`?

Comment: The driver has likely decided that TEILENUMMER is a numeric field (based on scanning the first x rows) and so any non-numeric values will get nulled out...  Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681032/excel-data-extraction-issue-with-column-data-type

Comment: Other related posts on SO: https://www.google.com/search?q=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0+column+datatypes+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: ...if you set the Excel format for that column to "Text" (ie. not "General") that should fix it.