# During Package Execution, How to sort columns in excel based on the length of some column when loading excel data into table in SSIS

Tags: ssis

We have a excel which has some 10 columns like "Query", "table", "Columns" exc.. Among this columns, only query column has highest length of data. but in excel, the first row is showing a smallest length of data in query column so when execution of package, the length of the query automatically set to lowest length. because of that, during package execution, i am getting truncation error. If i want to sort out this issue,  i need to manually bring the highest length column first but if i want to do this by package then how can i do?

Package - which has only one DFT where we have only one excel source and oldb destination.

Note: The target table has the column length of nvarchar(max) for all columns

Comment: You can go to advanced settings (right click the data flow window in the task) and see advanced, and you can change the output lengths there.  Or not best case, but sort your data by that columns length, so the first record is the longest one to fix your issue that way.

Comment: Already tried to change the length of that column in advanced setting but not helped.

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551203/help-with-a-oledb-connection-string-for-excel-files  -- the problem is that excel will modify the length of the columns at run time.  These registry settings will change that behavior