# DataType detection not working the same with CSV vs Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, csv, .net-core, odbc

There seems to be a problem with the ODBC driver's ability to detect mixed columns. I have this column:

```
Value
-----
24
200
AM1
AM2
55
22
```

Which is obviously mixed type.

When reading it with this connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={dataSource};Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"
```

And then trying to use the schema information as such

```
DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);
DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
reader.Close();

foreach (DataRow r in schemaTable.Rows)
{
    new
    {
        ColumnName = r["ColumnName"].ToString(),
        ColumnDataType = r["DataType"].ToString(),
        ColumnOrdinal = (int)r["ColumnOrdinal"],
        ColumnSize = (int)r["ColumnSize"]
     };
}
```

This works, as `ColumnDataType` will be populated with `System.String` which is what is expected.

But with this connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={dataSource};Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties="text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"
```

`ColumnDataType` always ends up being populated with `System.Int32` which leads to a bunch of problems down the line for anyone trying to assume anything from the extracted schema info.

This is the `schema.ini` when reading the CSV

```
[file.csv]
Format=Delimited(,)
ColNameHeader=True
DateTimeFormat=yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss
DecimalSymbol=.
CharacterSet=65001
```

I don't know exactly why 65001 is used there, but I've tried OEM and ANSI, no go. I've also tried adding `IMEX=1` to the connection string when reading the CSV, no go either.

Any ideas ? Is this a limitation of the driver ?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\[VERSION]\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\`, and compare the values on the "Excel" and "Text" keys. On my machine (VERSION=16.0), the Excel key has ImportMixedTypes="Text", and the "Text" key has ImportMixedTypes="Majory Type". So, I'm assuming that the text driver is choosing `int`, because most values are int. When you try to read one of those text values, I'd expect it will produce a null value. It looks like these values can only be modified in the registry, and can't be specified in the connection string: [Help with a OleDB connection string for excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551203)

If you change the "Text" key ImportMixedTypes to "Text", I suspect it will fix your issue. However, since it is a machine-wide setting, it might break other code that uses that driver.

I would recommend finding an alternative to the ACE drivers. There are many CSV and Excel libraries available for .NET that wouldn't have these kinds of issuess