# Prevent Export from Excel "Number as Text" Reformat to Scientific Notation

Tags: vb.net, excel, number-formatting

I'm trying to export data from Excel, and one of the columns is populated with IDs that often look like large numbers. For example, one cell will contain : 100,200,300,330,430,500... I am trying to export this data into a string variable using VB.NET, but whenever the number is large enough, the value converts to scientific notation.

I've checked out the second solution at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429853/scientific-notation-when-importing-from-excel-in-net), but I'm hoping the code I'm already using can be tweaked instead of having to rewrite using OleDB.

The code I use for the problem cell is this:

```
importData.Predecessors = cellRange(1, CInt(fieldMapping.Predecessors)).Value
```

Comment: Instead of Value, do you have a property for Text?

Comment: That worked wonders. I didn't realize "Text" was an option since it didn't come up in intellisense.