# Reading exponential values from excel file result in loosing data

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, oledb

I am reading a `xls` file using `OLEDB` connection string

```
mCon.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + mstrFilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\"");
```

I have deliberately set `IMEX = 1`, so that i can read all values as text as  my xls sheet contains mix data type.

Now in xls sheet there is columns that contains exponential values eg `4.0416E+14` which has internal value `404160301389870`. Now the problem is when i read the xls, it reads the exponential values instead of internal value, thus causing lose of data. How can i solve this problem. Please suggest !!!

Comment: [How to read internal value from Excel](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20how%20to%20read%20internal%20value%20from%20excel%20cell)

Comment: You have to edit the excel only. What you can do is: Select Column or cell > FormatCells > Select Custom > and Type: enter 14 zeroes as you have 14 digits.

Comment: Try this [Scientific notation when importing from Excel in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429853/scientific-notation-when-importing-from-excel-in-net)