# Reading an Excel into a Datatable with C# incorrectly formats numbers

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

Please do let me know if this is a duplicate; I couldn't find an actual answer..

Found this, related one,

[Scientific notation when importing from Excel in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429853/scientific-notation-when-importing-from-excel-in-net)

But it is several years old

So I am reading an Excel file, into a `DataTable` with `C#`.

My code is as follows:

```
string conStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;\"", filePath);
 System.Data.DataTable fileData = new System.Data.DataTable();
     using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
     {
         connection.Open();
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sheetName))
         {
             sheetName = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
         }
          string selectCmd = string.Format(sqlSelect, sheetName);
          using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectCmd, connection))
          using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
          {
             adapter.Fill(fileData);
          }
      }
```

So this reads everything in and populates my `DataTable`

Further through the code I perform validations on some of the content. I'm using `RegEx` for this.

However, I am running into an issue, where the numbers are being formatted to a scientific notation, or exponential format.

For example, I have `0.000083` and it is being read in as `8.3e-005`

So - how can I read in the excel file, and keep the original  `0.000083` ?

I'm good with bringing everything in as a string if needed... I've played with the extended properties, but nothing seems to affect how the data is read.

Looking for a solution that negates me having to add each individual cell to the datatable

**UPDATE**

The other thing I can do, in the meantime, Is convert a scientific-notation to a decimal, and then check that. Though ideally I would like to just bring in without the notation in the first place.

Comment: I think you need no regex tag here.

Comment: which type of data is set on the column filled with the numbers on the datatable? is decimal, double, float, string? Also, where do you see the scientific notation?

Comment: @Gusman - the data in the excel is General. We've played with different types on the input file. Seems that OleDB changes it to the notation when reading in. I see that when i get the value to validate.

Comment: What I mean is what type has the data on the DataTable once it's read, not in the excel sheet.

Comment: Gotcha - everything is a string.