# SELECT Command Doesn't Copy All Data

Tags: vb.net, excel, oledbconnection

i was copying my data from Excel to datagridview by using `SELECT` statements. But it wasn't show well..

The data show like this

[image]

but my excel data

[image]

my code :

```
Dim CON As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""D:\OTDR_DATA\" & TextBox1.Text & "\PRODUCT_CAREER.XLS"";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"";")
Dim DA As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [PRODUCT_CAREER$]", CON)
DA.Fill(DS)
DataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)
```

Does anyone know why this can be? i have search on the google, but not a such question like this..

Comment: How many cells in "Parent Parts" column have numbers only before that numeric code is encountered?

Comment: The numberic column first, all have 2070 rows in the Parent, I also have tried to change the 73502 became A735032 in the first row. But result still be same

Comment: Show 'transfering' code ..

Comment: what is the transferring code?
That is the code to show the data from Excel to my datagridview.. Just only that already work

Comment: Try making the very first cell in column "Parent Parts" alphanumeric, e.g. Axxxxxx. Not the last cell before B8070HB, but the very first cell in the column

Comment: I have tried it. A73502. But, it became the first cell cannot be show up

Comment: Code that DS.tables(0).rows(x) that copied to datagrid ..

Comment: This question has your answer.  It's because the Jet engine scans the rows to determine type. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298726/accessing-excel-spreadsheet-with-c-sharp-occasionally-returns-blank-value-for-so

Comment: @matzone That's all the code i have to copy,, no more again..

Comment: Please don't SHOUT your questions. Posting them IN ALL CAPS makes them harder to read, and it's annoying. (It's also considered rude to SHOUT.) You won't get an answer any faster by typing in CAPS. The Shift keys are on your keyboard for a reason; posting in proper case makes text easier to read and understand. Please use them. Thanks.

Comment: Ok,, thanks for your advice. But i got reply soon even it's CAPS. LOL

Comment: @Jesse Hello, +1 for you suggestion sir.. Thanks, but that solution can't solve in my problem. Thanks for your time sir.. And thanks all for who had comment.. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel driver determines type of data in the column by first 8 (by default) rows. I have a feeling, that you have a lot of numeric data in that column before alphanumeric is encountered.

To change that behavior you need to set Registry key `TypeGuessRows` to `0`. The location of the key depends on which driver you use in your connection string (Jet, AccessConnectivityEngine etc.)

[Here](http://support.sas.com/kb/35/563.html) is detailed instruction on how to change the setting.

Comment: Yes, you are right,, my first 8++ rows was integer value.. then how to change the registry?

Comment: Can you please post your connection string?

Comment: Thank you. I have added a link to instructions how to change the setting

Comment: So up to:  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ► Software ► Microsoft ► Office ► 12.0` everything is there but no `► Access Connectivity Engine ► Engines` after that? If so, do you have  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ► Software ► Microsoft ► Office ► 14.0` ?

Comment: Galanter Bravo sir.. I have 14.0 , after i change.. It run well.. Thanks so much for your time sir..